# laravel 8 Target class [ColorController] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

1. I created `ColorController` Class using

```
php artisan make:controller ColorController
```

The class has been created successfully and exists in the App/HTTP/Controller folder.

2. I defined route like this

```
Route::get('color/text', [ColorController::class, 'text']);
```

3. And a Method in the Contoller Class like this

   ```
      namespace App\Http\Controllers;

      use Illuminate\Http\Request;

      class ColorController extends Controller
         {
              public function text()
             {
                  return 'Color Controller';
             }
         }
   ```
4. I visited the like this

   `http://localhost:8000/color/text`

It shows the error message as below

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [ColorController] does not exist.
http://localhost:8000/color/text
```

Where did I make the fault? where to correct the process?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Solution like this...

I had to add this line above in the web.php file

use App\HTTP\Controllers\ColorController;

Now all works fine.